# Others can upload to youtube mychennal or add video to my youtube playlist in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I want to other user can upload video to my chennal list or add video to my play list in my ios app? its possible for in youtube api?

I done with user can upload and add play list on user account. But i dont no other user how to